# Coroutine is only running for my first rendered object (unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My coroutine is only firing once for the first rendered red cube. The other ones in my beat map get rendered but do not move to the desired position of (5,5). Am i missing something? Thanks in advance!

I tried adding a while loop, but that did not seem to fix the problem.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class BeatMapConductor : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CSVReader beatmap;
    private MusicConductor music;

    private Vector3 redEndPosition = new Vector2(5,5);
    private Vector3 redStartPosition;
    private float desirecDuration = 5f;
    private float elapsedTime;
    private int i;

    private Queue<UnityEngine.GameObject> queue;
    private UnityEngine.GameObject[] array;


    // initializes variables before game starts
    void Awake()
    {
        beatmap = GetComponent<CSVReader>();
        music = GetComponent<MusicConductor>();
    }

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        i = 0;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
        int roundedBeat = (int)Math.Round(music.songPositionInBeats, 0);

        if(i < beatmap.myPlayerList.player.Length && roundedBeat == beatmap.myPlayerList.player[i].beat){
            //rendering a new cube
            // Create a new cube primitive to set the color on
            GameObject redCube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
            // Get the Renderer component from the new cube
            var cubeRenderer = redCube.GetComponent<Renderer>();
            // Call SetColor using the shader property name "_Color" and setting the color to red
            cubeRenderer.material.SetColor("_Color", Color.red);
            
            i++;
            StartCoroutine(Movement(redCube));
        }

         
    } 

    IEnumerator Movement(GameObject cube){
        // to move the game object
        redStartPosition = cube.transform.position;
        while(elapsedTime < desirecDuration){
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            float percentageComplete = elapsedTime / desirecDuration;
            cube.transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(redStartPosition, redEndPosition, percentageComplete);
        }
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run `Movement` for the first time, it will increase `elapsedTime` to at least 5. When you now run `Movement` a second time, `elapsedTime` is still at least 5 thus `while (elapsedTime < desirecDuration)` will evaluate to `false` and your second cube will not be moved. You should make `elapsedTime` a local variable of the coroutine (and `redStartPosition` too).
Also, you should place `yield return null;` at the end within the `while` loop to have the cube moving on a frame basis. The way you have written it the loop will bump `elapsedTime` to 5 immediately in one frame.

```
IEnumerator Movement(GameObject cube) {
    float elapsedTime = 0f; // make it local for every coroutine instance
    // to move the game object
    Vector3 redStartPosition = cube.transform.position;
    while (elapsedTime < desirecDuration) {
        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
        float percentageComplete = elapsedTime / desirecDuration;
        cube.transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(redStartPosition, redEndPosition, percentageComplete);
        yield return null; // on loop run per frame
    }
}
```